# Powershell timer : no action is launched

Tags: c, .net, winforms, powershell, timer

I want my timer to consult a file (consigne.csv) and display the "consigne" column according to the date I defined.
The data of this file would be regularly modified, hence the choice of the timer.
The form opens with the correct information but the information is not updated.
Thanks for your help.

Script :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

################ TIMER ##################################

    $Timer = new-object System.Windows.forms.timer
    $Timer.Interval = 1000 

    #Action.
    $Timer.Add_Tick({
                       #Interval after boot.
                        $Timer.Interval = (5000)
                       #Command
                        $global:today = get-date -format "dd/MM/yy"
                        $global:DesktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
                        $global:TxtConsigne= (import-csv "$DesktopPath\consigne.csv" -encoding UTF8 -delimiter ";")
                        $global:Message = ($TxtConsigne | where-object {$_.EXPIRATION -ge $today})

                    })

################ Form #####################################

#Form

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 0,570
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1920,260)
    
# Consigne
    
    $Consigne           = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
    $Consigne.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 210,20
    $Consigne.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1500,220)
    $Form.Controls.Add($Consigne)

################################################################################################################

# $DesktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
# $TxtConsigne= (import-csv "$DesktopPath\consigne.csv" -encoding UTF8 -delimiter ";")
# $Message = ($TxtConsigne | where-object {$_.EXPIRATION -ge $today})

$Timer.Start()

    if ($Message){

        $Message | FOREACH{
            
        $Mess += "- " + $_.Consigne + "`n"
            
            $Consigne.Text = $Mess      
        }

        $Mess=$null




        #Affichage de la fenêtre uniquement si consigne à passer
        [void]$Form.ShowDialog()

    }
    
$Timer.Stop()
```

and content of consigne.csv

> DATE;EXPIRATION;CONSIGNE; 12/09/20;15/09/20;Message 4;
> 11/09/20;11/09/20;Message 3; 10/09/20;11/09/20;Message 2;
> 10/09/20;10/09/20;Message 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those `$global:xxx` variables in the Timer event handler; just one for the path to the CSV file would be enough. Also, it could do with a lesser scope: `$script:xxx`.

Then, you are comparing a date as formatted string in format `dd/MM/yy` which does not compare like you think, since the day comes earlier than the month. (it is a non-sortable date format).

Always try to compare datetime objects to other datetime objects.

Try:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

# the path to the csv file used in the timer event handler.
$csvPath = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'consigne.csv'

################ Form #####################################

#Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 0,570
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1920,260)

# Consigne
$Consigne           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Consigne.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 210,20
$Consigne.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1500,200)
$Form.Controls.Add($Consigne)

################ TIMER ##################################

$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.forms.timer
$Timer.Enabled = $false  # disabled at first
$Timer.Interval = 50     # initial timer interval 

# Timer Action.
$Timer.Add_Tick({
    $this.Interval = 5000              # inside the event handler, you can refer to the control with `$this`
    $Consigne.Text = [string]::Empty   # clear the label
    # read the CSV file, get the items with an EXPIRATION date greater
    # or equal to today and write the CONSIGNE messages to the label
    (Import-Csv -Path $script:csvPath -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";") |
    Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.EXPIRATION, 'dd/MM/yy', $null) -ge (Get-Date).Date } |
    ForEach-Object {$Consigne.Text += "- {0}`r`n" -f $_.CONSIGNE }
})

# start the timer as soon as the form is shown
$Form.Add_Shown({$Timer.Enabled = $true; $Timer.Start()})
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()

# clean up the Timer and Form objects
$Timer.Dispose()
$Form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Fantastic ! it's working ! Thank you for your clear explanation and the addition of comments which allowed me to understand. Thank you also for the reorganization of the script. I did not expect so much! Thank you Théo ;-)